# selecting first td from all rows using css selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Here is my html

```
<table id="mytable" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr >
            <td>1888</td>
            <td>Michael</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>1886</td>
            <td>Bosco</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>955</td>
            <td>Raj</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

i want to select first td from all rows

So output will be 1888, 1886, 955

I tried this `table[id='mytable'] tr:nth-child`
but it throws error.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you want you need to change the selector you're using to: `table[id='mytable'] tr td:first-child`. This will select the first `td` in every `tr` in the `table` with the ID `mytable`

The code in the snippet is just an example of how to apply it

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table[id='mytable'] tr td:first-child").css({'background-color':'pink'});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr >
            <td>1888</td>
            <td>Michael</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>1886</td>
            <td>Bosco</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>955</td>
            <td>Raj</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `first-child` selector on `td` elements:

```
#mytable td:first-child {
  background: red;
}
```